# Using tab completion to type filename faster in the Start > Run or Windows Explorer addres bar

Tags: windows-explorer

I used to filename completion in the command line using a tab button.

I’m interesting is there a way to work in the same manner in the Run window (Start > Run) or in Windows Explorer’s address bar?

Maybe there is a convenient third party tool allowing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Internet Explorer. From the Tools menu click Internet Options.
In the Advanced tab, enable "Use inline AutoComplete in File Explorer and Run Dialog", and click OK. (Source: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/autosuggest-autocomplete-explorer-address-bar-run-dialog/)